# The totient of a factor of a number divides the totient of the number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given any number and one of its factors, how can you show that the totient of the factor divides the totient of the original number?

Comment: What do you mean $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)+\phi(n)$?

Comment: I know that the totient of a number is equal to the sum of the totient of each of its factors so could we not make that statement since mn can be factored into m and n?

Answer (score 2):

- If $p\mid n$ then $\phi(pn)=p\phi(n)$.
- If $p\nmid n$ then $\phi(pn)=(p-1)\phi(n)$.

Comment: How would I exactly use this? I don't have that either m or n are prime.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Hagen's answer: Let $m\mid n$, we need to show that $\phi(m)\mid\phi(n)$. If $m$ is prime then we are done, since $\phi(pm)=p\phi(m)$. If $m$ is not prime, then it can be decomposed into a product of primes, say $\prod p^\alpha$. Then

$$\phi(m)=\phi(\prod p^\alpha)=\prod p^{\alpha-1}\prod(p-1).$$

Now, $\phi(n)$ can be expressed as this product times the totient function of all the extra prime factors $n$ has that is not in $m$. Think of this as because we have "taken out" all the prime powers of $m$ to get that product, and we can do the same thing for $n$ and still have "leftovers". The conclusion follows.